# PostgreSQL connection issue with .NET Core

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core-6.0

I am using **PostgreSQL** with **.NET Core 6 Web API**. But I am continuously getting the following error.
022-06-27 12:06:47.4763|ERROR|
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpServer

Connection ID "17005592284755918893", Request ID "8000002e-0015-ec00-b63f-84710c7967bb": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.

```
Npgsql.NpgsqlOperationInProgressException (0x80004005): The connection is already in state 'Executing'
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.<StartUserAction>g__DoStartUserAction|255_0(<>c__DisplayClass255_0& )
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.StartUserAction(ConnectorState newState, NpgsqlCommand command, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean attemptPgCancellation)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.Reset(Boolean async)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.CloseAsync(Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.CloseAsync()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.CloseAsync()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalTransaction.ClearTransactionAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalTransaction.DisposeAsync()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.ResetStateAsync(Boolean disposeDbConnection)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.<DisposeAsync>g__Await|22_0(Int32 i, ValueTask vt, List`1 toDispose)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.DisposeAsync()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.<DisposeAsync>g__Await|22_0(Int32 i, ValueTask vt, List`1 toDispose)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.RequestServicesFeature.<DisposeAsync>g__Awaited|9_0(RequestServicesFeature servicesFeature, ValueTask vt)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContext.FireOnCompleted()
```

Here is the connection string I am using

```
"DefaultConnection": "server=localhost;port=5432;userid=user_admin;database=dbName;password=pass@123;"
```

also getting the below error

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection

An error occurred using the connection to database 'db_name' on server 'tcp://localhost:5432'.
```

I am new in PostgreSQL. Does anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: Can you please share the code which leads to such issue? A full [mre] would be great.

Comment: Also my guess would be that you are trying to execute several queries in parallel on the same context which is not supported AFAIK.

Comment: @GuruStron, I am not sure how this error is producing. I am using nlog for logging the error and getting this error email continuously. I am using the repository pattern to access to dbContext. there is no stacktrace in the email. I just publish the website today and getting this error. Don't know how can I find and fix it

Comment: This error only show after you publish the website?

Comment: @XinranShen yes, I never find it at local while developing

Comment: You can try to add `Integrated Security=False` in your connectionstring.